# Iteration Results in trx output

Tags: visual-studio-2010, mstest, lab-management

I have been running tests as part of a build for quite some time now (TFS, VS2010, MTM, Lab Management) and have always received the Iteration Data results in MTM (opened in VS2010) via .trx files. After applying some updates to the VMs I to deploy to and run tests (deploy to server and run tests on client within one environment) I no longer receive the iteration data results only the overall 'pass/fail' with system data and a log (as set in my Testsettings in MTM).

I have compared the trx file output with previous builds and the past builds have lines such as:

```
UnitTestResult executionId="" parentExecutionId="" testId="" testName="Login_Invalid" computerName="client" duration="" startTime="" endTime="" testType="" outcome="Passed" testListId="" relativeResultsDirectory="" dataRowInfo="0" resultType="DataDrivenDataRow"
```

*I have removed most of the text, the fields are what's important.*
These lines are missing now.

Is there a setting I have to change to have this data collected and returned to MTM?

The Environment I am aiming to get iteration data results from is comprised of a Web Server (Win Server 2008 R2) and a Web Client (XP). Not sure what other information is relevant as there are a lot of places I have investigated thus far (Test Settings, Test Controller Config, Test Agent Configs), so feel free to comment for further info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much time has passed and I had started getting the results back without really trying anything specific. I will list the things that have changed since then so others may benefit:

- Remade whole Environment
- New Test Controller
- Double checked all permissions of ServiceAccount
- Installed all updates to VS2010

The exact time that these result started being returned are not definite however the time we lost them seemed to correlate with the installation of a Microsoft Hotfix to reduce TFS Backup sizes. This was not re-installed in recreating the Environments and while I cannot guarantee it, that's where I would be looking to if it happened again.

Hope this helps someone! Please post an answer if one of these methods helps you and I will update the Accepted Answer.